# Strange strace and setuid behaviour: permission denied under strace, but not running normally

Tags: shell-script, strace, setuid

This is related to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/247441/allow-user-to-execute-a-shell-script-without-seeing-its-contents).

I have a script (`fix-permissions.sh`) that fixes some file permissions:

```
#! /bin/bash 
sudo chown -R person:group /path/
sudo chmod -R g+rw /path/
```

And a small c program to run this, which is `setuid`ed:

```
#include "sys/types.h"
#include "unistd.h"
int main(){
    setuid(geteuid());
    return system("/path/fix-permissions.sh");
}
```

Directory:

```
-rwsr-xr-x  1 root  root  7228 Feb 19 17:33 fix-permissions
-rwx--x--x  1 root  root   112 Feb 19 13:38 fix-permissions.sh
```

If I do this, everything seems fine, and the permissions do get correctly fixed:

```
       james $ sudo su someone-else
someone-else $ ./fix-permissions
```

but if I use strace, I get:

```
someone-else $ strace ./fix-permissions
/bin/bash: /path/fix-permissions.sh: Permission denied
```

It's interesting to note that I get the same permission denied error with an **identical** setup (permissions, c program), but a different script, even when not using strace. Is this some kind of heureustic magic behaviour in setuid that I'm uncovering?

How should I figure out what's going on?

System is Ubuntu 10.04.2 LTS, Linux 2.6.32.26-kvm-i386-20101122 #1 SMP

Comment: Some possible other reasons:
[colored output slower](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36964/ls-behaves-differently-under-strace),
[timing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53598305/what-could-make-a-program-behaves-differently-inside-strace)
([another](https://superuser.com/questions/1641282/why-does-strace-change-command-behavior)),
[setuid/setgid bit](https://superuser.com/questions/247888/strange-strace-and-setuid-behaviour-permission-denied-under-strace-but-not-run),
([another](https://superuser.com/questions/1059198/why-strace-sudo-command-bombs-when-sudo-command-works))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Linux ignores the *setuid* bit when running a process under `strace` or similar programs.

- Linux-Kernel mailing list, [Re: 2.4.16 + strace 4.4 + setuid programs](http://lkml.indiana.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/0112.0/1528.html):

  > From: Manfred Spraul
  >   Date: Thu Dec 06 2001 - 12:25:53 EST
  >
  > > If you want to strace setuid things and have the setuid bit
  > >     honored, you have to run strace as root with the -u option.
  >
  > No, even that's not possible anymore.
  >   setuid is now always ignored if a process is ptraced, even if root
  >   is ptracing - that's the fix for the latest ptrace root exploit
  >   (2.4.1x).

which is probably talking about:

- [Linux Kernel 2.2.x - 2.4.x ptrace/kmod Local Root Exploit](http://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/3/) at Exploit-DB

  ([CVE-2003-0127](http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2003-0127), [OSVDB-4565](http://osvdb.org/show/osvdb/4565))
- [SANS: Malware FAQ: How does the Ptrace exploit work on Linux?](http://www.sans.org/security-resources/malwarefaq/Ptrace.php)

Comment: Okay, so in summary: `setuid` has so many security holes that I just shouldn't expect it to work, and ever using it ever is a very bad idea?

Comment: @Autopulated: No. My post only describes *one* exploit, from 2003, not "many". And it is *careless use* of setuid, not the feature itself, that leads to security holes. Carefully written programs work fine. It is best to avoid setuid, however, , and *especially* in your "Gmail password" case (for which I have suggested a different solution).