# Why strace sudo command bombs when sudo command works?

Tags: sudo, strace, setuid

my username is allowed to execute

`sudo` command

then why does this bomb

`strace sudo` command

with the error:

`sudo: must be setuid root`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The "must be setuid root" is caused by running sudo in strace.

From man strace:

> BUGS
>   Programs that use the setuid bit do not have effective user ID
>   privileges while being traced.

If you want to strace setuid things and have the setuid bit honored, you have to run strace as root with the -u option (this question has already been submitted : [Strange strace and setuid behaviour: permission denied under strace, but not running normally](https://superuser.com/questions/247888/strange-strace-and-setuid-behaviour-permission-denied-under-strace-but-not-run))

Comment: OK but, "command" does not have setuid bit.  I am able to run it as root because that is how the `sudoers` file is setup.

Comment: Oh I see, it is not about "command", it is about "sudo" - sudo has setuid set.

Comment: Yes, you got it.

Comment: Why not `sudo strace ...`?

Comment: `sudo strace` will run `strace` with root privileges, but will not trace `sudo`.