# Is it possible to strace pinging a host?

Tags: linux, networking, strace

I am doing this

```
$ strace -f ping -s 1 www.google.com
execve("/bin/ping", ["ping", "-s", "1", "www.google.com"],
   [/* 80 vars */]) = 0
getuid()                                = 1001
setuid(1001)                            = 0
getuid()                                = 1001
geteuid()                               = 1001
capget({_LINUX_CAPABILITY_VERSION_3, 0}, NULL) = 0
capget({_LINUX_CAPABILITY_VERSION_3, 0}, {0, 0, 0}) = 0  
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_ICMP) = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 3
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(1025), 
     sin_addr=inet_addr("74.125.28.105")}, 16) = 0
write(3, "ping: icmp open socket: Operatio"..., 48
     ping: icmp open socket: Operation not permitted) = 48
close(3)                                = 0
exit_group(2)                           = ?
+++ exited with 2 +++
```

I have excluded a lot of extraneous lines but the crux of the matter is that it is returning exit code 2.

I am receiving exit code 0 if I execute the ping without stracing.

Am I missing some options when running strace ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why strace sudo command bombs when sudo command works?](https://superuser.com/questions/1059198/why-strace-sudo-command-bombs-when-sudo-command-works)

Answer (score 4):

This is a valid question and it is not a duplicate of the `strace sudo` command.  At one time in the past the `/bin/ping` was a `setuid` executable, so at some point in the past, perhaps it was a duplicate but it isn't a dupe today.

`sudo` is a `setuid` executable.  `ping` uses `cap_net_raw`.  So, I believe the answer is that `strace` also needs to be granted `cap_net_raw`:

```
setcap cap_net_raw+p /usr/bin/strace
```

This worked for me.

Or... perhaps the `setuid`/`cap_net_raw` situation is a function of distro.  I am using RHEL 7.