# Why does strace change command behavior?

Tags: linux, strace

I'm trying to use [PICpgm](http://picpgm.picprojects.net) to program a Microchip connected via GPIO.  I'm running Raspbian Buster on a Pi 4B.  Running as root, this command returns with no error but it doesn't print anything useful.  If I run the same command through `strace` then it works correctly.  What can explain this?  `strace` adds a huge CPU overhead so I would like to find a way to fix this.

```
# picpgm -r

==================================================================
PICPgm 2.9.3.1
PIC Development Programmer, http://picpgm.picprojects.net
Copyright 2002-2018 Christian Stadler (picpgm@picprojects.net)
built on Jun 17 2018, 09:26:06
==================================================================

Autodetecting Programmer ...
GPIO: access via /sys/class/gpio
Programmer: GPIO Programmer (Raspberry Pi)
            at GPIO

Autodetecting PIC ...

finished in 2.0 seconds!
```

```
# strace -o /dev/null picpgm -r

==================================================================
PICPgm 2.9.3.1
PIC Development Programmer, http://picpgm.picprojects.net
Copyright 2002-2018 Christian Stadler (picpgm@picprojects.net)
built on Jun 17 2018, 09:26:06
==================================================================

Autodetecting Programmer ...
GPIO: access via /sys/class/gpio
Programmer: GPIO Programmer (Raspberry Pi)
            at GPIO

Autodetecting PIC ...

PIC name:    PIC18F67J60
Device ID:   0x1F23
Flash:       128 kByte
EEPROM:      0 Byte


finished in 3.0 seconds!
```

Comment: I see you (perhaps wisely) asked this same question on the official [Raspberry Pi forum](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=309340)

Comment: *"What can explain this?"* -- Timing.  The execution of the program is slowed down ever so slightly as each syscall (e.g. read/write requests) is logged.  Apparently the communication with the device is sensitive to the program's execution speed.

Comment: @sawdust thank you that was just the clue I needed!  Running `yes` in the background also makes it work.  Hmm.  I guess I need to talk to the app developer.

Comment: Some possible other reasons:
[colored output slower](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36964/ls-behaves-differently-under-strace),
[timing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53598305/what-could-make-a-program-behaves-differently-inside-strace)
([another](https://superuser.com/questions/1641282/why-does-strace-change-command-behavior)),
[setuid/setgid bit](https://superuser.com/questions/247888/strange-strace-and-setuid-behaviour-permission-denied-under-strace-but-not-run),
([another](https://superuser.com/questions/1059198/why-strace-sudo-command-bombs-when-sudo-command-works))